# Add condition to request. NodeJs and sheetdb-node

Tags: node.js

I can see from the documentation that it's possible to add conditions like <, >, <=, >= to HTTP request:

```
 https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/58f61be4dda40/search?id=<3
```

Is it possible to do the same with the sheetdb-node lib?

```
client.read({ search: { id: startIndex, isFree: "TRUE" } }).then(function(data) {
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement conditions like `<, >, <=, >=` in this manner

`https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/58f61be4dda40/search?id=<3`

```js
client.read({ search: { id: "<3"} }).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}, function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

`https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/58f61be4dda40/search?id=>3`

```js
client.read({ search: { id: ">3"} }).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}, function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

`https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/58f61be4dda40/search?id=>=3`

```js
client.read({ search: { id: ">=3"} }).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}, function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

`https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/58f61be4dda40/search?id=<=3`

```js
client.read({ search: { id: "<=3"} }).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}, function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/JaganKaartik/6e4dc18c5ec24c1abdb7594ed06b3937

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer!